# Python Pip Error :: legacy-install-failure

Tags: python, error-handling, pip

I am trying to install zbar but I get this error and my pip version is the latest version.[image]

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) ? `sudo apt-get install libzbar0`

Comment: I don't have apt I am using arch so I run pip install zbar.is there is any problem?

Comment: Then use `pacman` to install `zbar`, after that `pip install zbar`

Comment: it is worked. with pacman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for installing zbar in Arch need to run this command : sudo pacman -S zbar